# Select counties containing a specific set of Surnames

Tags: sqlite

If I have a very large table of names with three columns - name, surname and county, as follows:

```
name surname county
John Williams Broward
Steve Milne Broward
Mary Granville Mahony
Josephine Jackson Kent
Jane Wright Kent
...
```

what would be the best approach for finding the counties that contain all the following surnames: Griffy, Griffey and Griffin. I would like the result to contain the count of the least common name in that county. So if Kent county contains 5 Griffins, 4 Griffys and 1 Griffey, I would like to see the following as part of the result:

```
Kent 1
```

This is as far as I got:

```
select county, surname, count(*) from census_data where surname = "Griffin" or surname = "Griffy" or surname == "Griffey" group by county, surname;
```

I'm not sure if this is even the correct approach to finding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `CTE` that returns all the counties that contain all the surnames that you search for and then use `RANK()` window function:

```
with cte as (
  select county,
    sum(surname = 'Griffin') counter1, 
    sum(surname = 'Griffy') counter2,
    sum(surname = 'Griffey') counter3
  from census_data 
  where surname in ('Griffin', 'Griffy', 'Griffey')
  group by county 
  having counter1 * counter2 * counter3 > 0
)
select county, min(counter1, counter2, counter3) least_common_name_counter
from (
  select *, rank() over (order by min(counter1, counter2, counter3)) rank
  from cte
)
where rank = 1
```

or if you want results for all counties:

```
with cte as (
  select county,
    sum(surname = 'Griffin') counter1, 
    sum(surname = 'Griffy') counter2,
    sum(surname = 'Griffey') counter3
  from census_data 
  where surname in ('Griffin', 'Griffy', 'Griffey')
  group by county 
  having counter1 * counter2 * counter3 > 0
)
select county, min(counter1, counter2, counter3) least_common_name_counter
from cte
```